# Servlet URI set in an inappropriate way when sending a response through a servlet

Tags: tomcat, servlets, redirect, tomcat7

I have my web application available on `http://somedomain.com:8080/myapp/`.

I have an alias to this domain: `somealias.com`.

When I locally send a redirect to a relatively-given address, response headers have their location as I have set it (`http://somealias.com/somePage.html`).

When on `http://somedomain.com:8080/myapp`, the location is set to `http://somedomain.com:8080/myapp/somePage.html`.

However, when on `http://somealias.com`, somehow the location changes to `http://somealias.com/MYAPP/somePage.html` - probably because of the domain.

I would like to know if there is a way to deal with it, because then the redirect goes to `http://somealias.com/myapp/somePage.html` which of course doesn't exist and the server sends 404 code.

It's this part `myapp` that I don't want to have - the alias `http://somealias.com` directs to the url `http://somedomain.com/8080/myapp`, so when a user is redirected to `http://somealias.com/myapp/`, in fact he is being redirected to `http://somedomain.com:8080/myapp/myapp` - which, of course, doesn't exist.

In the code, I just do

```
response.sendRedirect("somePage.html)";
```

Sorry for the inappropriate format of the links - it is because of my low reputation.

Comment: Can you clean this up a bit? You have `...` and `~` and other stuff that are confusing the issue. Can you give "full" example (if dummy) URLs, please?

Comment: I edited it - hope it would be more readable. I can't do anything with '...' because of my low reputation - I can't post whole URLs.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed the formatting of the URLs to make it more readable. When you redirect, you should use a URL with a leading `/`. When you say that your application "redirects" `http://somealias.com/foo` -> `http://somedomain.com:8080/myapp/foo`, are you "forwarding" that URL or are you redirecting it (by sending a 30x response to the client and having them make a new request)?